# Schwarzian Derivative

Tags: derivatives

Determine the Schwarzian derivative of the following function: 
a.$$ f(x)= ax^2 + bx +c$$
b.$$ g(x) = x^3 + (1/2)x$$
c. $$h(x) = x^n $$ with n greater than or equal to 3

so I got the following answer, (I just wanted to amke sure they're correct/can't be reduced):
a.$$ sf(x) = (-6a^2)/(2ax+b)^2$$
b.$$ sg(x) = (-36x^2+3)/(9x^4+3x^2$+1/4)$$
c.$$ sh(x) = ((n^3)x^(n-3)-3n^2x^{n-3}+2nx^{n-3}-(3/2)(n-1)x^{-1} $$(especially unsure about this one)

Thanks!